# Django HTMLCalendar Previous and Next Month won't show

Tags: python, html, django

I am quite new to Django and am currently building an app to display a calendar using Django. I've been following the tutorial [here](https://www.huiwenteo.com/normal/2018/07/29/django-calendar-ii.html) but I can't make the previous and next month button to work. When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/calendar I can see this month's calendar, but when I press previous / next month nothing happens, only the url changes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/calendar/?month=[this_year]-[this_month+/-1] Here is my View Class:

```
class CalendarView(generic.ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'calendar.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        d_obj = get_date(self.request.GET.get('day', None))

        cal = Calendar(d_obj.year, d_obj.month)

        html_cal = cal.formatmonth(withyear=True)
        context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)

        d_obj = get_date(self.request.GET.get('month', None))
        context['prev_month'] = prev_month(d_obj)
        context['next_month'] = next_month(d_obj)

        return context

def get_date(req_day):
    if req_day:
        year, month = (int(x) for x in req_day.split('-'))
        return datetime(year, month, day=1)
    return datetime.today()

def prev_month(d_obj):
    first = d_obj.replace(day=1)
    prev_month = first - timedelta(days=1)
    month = 'month=' + str(prev_month.year) + '-' + str(prev_month.month)
    return month

def next_month(d_obj):
    days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(d_obj.year, d_obj.month)[1]
    last = d_obj.replace(day=days_in_month)
    next_month = last + timedelta(days=1)
    month = 'month=' + str(next_month.year) + '-' + str(next_month.month)
    return month
```

I'm using Django 2.2 so I did a few changes to the urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('calendar/', views.CalendarView.as_view(), name='calendar')
]
```

And this is the body part of the calendar.html file:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <a class="btn btn-info left" href="{% url 'calendar' %}?{{ prev_month }}"> Previous Month 
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-info right" href="{% url 'calendar' %}?{{ next_month }}"> Next Month 
    </a>
</div>

{{ calendar }}
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong around here?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late but for anyone else stuck on this problem here is the issue in the code above:

```
class CalendarView(generic.ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'calendar.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        **d_obj = get_date(self.request.GET.get('month', None))**

        cal = Calendar(d_obj.year, d_obj.month)

        html_cal = cal.formatmonth(withyear=True)
        context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
        context['prev_month'] = prev_month(d_obj)
        context['next_month'] = next_month(d_obj)

        return context
```